# create an uneditable character in ruby textfield

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to create an uneditable semicolon in Rails text field for a date.

For instance, the user can enter the hours and the minutes, while the semicolon already there and is not deletable.

```
 <%= text_field_tag(:start_time, '', class: "timepicker four", size: 5, 
  maxlength: 5, placeholder: 'HH:MM', value: 
  @booking_item.start_time.strftime('%H') + ":"+ 
  @booking_item.start_time.strftime('%M')) %>
```

Any solution for this in Ruby?

Thanks

Comment: People usually create two text fields for hours and minutes and put a label with a semicolon in between. Alternatively, one might handle input events and prevent a semicolon removal.

Comment: ...Or, rather than entering numbers manually, a common implementation is to use a javascript popup "clock" to select the time.

Comment: There are libraries for input masks which seems like what you are asking for. google "jquery input mask" and pick one that works for you